# Building a autocomplete search input with a combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a combobox that will fill with posible auto complete results, I firstly have all the words in an array that compares to the user input, its then put into a switch statement that adds the words to the combobox. I however can't get it right to remove the results from the combobox when the input changes.

```
var dictionary:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
dictionary.push("University Chapel");
dictionary.push("IT Building");
dictionary.push("Student Centre");
dictionary.push("EMS Building");
dictionary.push("EMB Building");
dictionary.push("Monastry Hall");
dictionary.push("Conference Centre");
dictionary.push("Client Service Centre");
var objects:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
stage.focus = inputBox;
inputBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onCompletions);
function onCompletions(event:Event):void{
for(var i:int = 0; i < dictionary.length; ++i){
    if(dictionary[i].indexOf(inputBox.text) >= 0){
        switch(dictionary[i])   {
            case 'IT Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"IT Building", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);  
                break;
            case 'University Chapel':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"University Chapel", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'Student Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Student Centre", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'EMS Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"EMS Building", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'EMB Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"EMB Building", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'Monastry Hall':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Monastry Hall", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'Conference Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Conference Centre", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;

            case 'Client Service Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Client Service Centre", data:"screenData" + newRow},0);
                break;
        }
    }
    else    {
        //cbox.removeAll(); //Where I attempted to remove all the results
    }
}
```

}

So I'm trying to remove the results from the combobox and have them re evaluated and then inserted again. Just as a side question is there a way to expand comboboxs through actionscript ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I got it to work, so this will basically create a autocomplete search input box.

```
var dictionary:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
dictionary.push("University Chapel");
dictionary.push("IT Building");
dictionary.push("Student Centre");
dictionary.push("EMS Building");
dictionary.push("EMB Building");
dictionary.push("Monastry Hall");
dictionary.push("Conference Centre");
dictionary.push("Client Service Centre");

stage.focus = inputBox;

inputBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onCompletions);
cbox.open();
function onCompletions(event:Event):void{
cbox.removeAll();
cbox.close();
for(var i:int = 0; i < dictionary.length; ++i){
    if(dictionary[i].indexOf(inputBox.text) >= 0 && inputBox.text != ''){
        switch(dictionary[i])   {
            case 'IT Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"IT Building", data:"screenData"},0); 
                cbox.open();
                break;
            case 'University Chapel':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"University Chapel", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'Student Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Student Centre", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'EMS Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"EMS Building", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'EMB Building':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"EMB Building", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'Monastry Hall':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Monastry Hall", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'Conference Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Conference Centre", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;

            case 'Client Service Centre':
                cbox.addItemAt({label:"Client Service Centre", data:"screenData"},0);
                cbox.open();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}